# how to give the permission of manage_mailbox on facebook apps

Tags: facebook

I am newly entered into facebook application. I want to send the message to facebook's users without mailid. I didn't possible. because i found the error is manage_mailbox is not have permission.

Let you know, how to resolve this.. I need ASAP.\
I have tried below like this

```
$url = "/100003508406494/inbox/";
          //100006378695734
          $message="Hai";
          $link='http://apps.facebook.com/jobsmate';
          $face=$facebook->api($url,'POST',
            array(
              'access_token' => $face_token,
              'method'=>'publish_streem',
              'message'=>$message,
              'link'=>$link,
              'name'=>'jobsmate',             
              'description'=>"$link",
              'picture'=>"http://jobsmate.wisdomjobs.com/images/jobsmateicon2.jpg"
                 ));
```

Comment: Could you pls elaborate, some code and what have you tried? It's highly not understood what you are asking! There's no such permission `manage_mailbox`, but there is `read_mailbox`

Answer (score 1):

`manage_mailbox` seems to be an incorrect error message from FB. I got the same message when i was trying to post a private message using Graph API which i found out later is not possible. You have to use either FB's send dialog or use XMPP chat interface to be able to send private messages now.